# Multiple CMakeLists

Tags: cmake

Suppose I have a directory structure as follows:

```
/main.cpp
/CMakeLists.txt
/foo/foo.cpp
/foo/CMakeLists.txt
```

where my `/CMakeLists.txt` file contains the following:

```
project(Test)
add_subdirectory("foo")
add_executable(Test main.cpp foo/foo.cpp)
target_link_libraries(Test ${OpenNI_LIB})
```

and my `/foo/CMakeLists.txt` file contains the following:

```
find_library(OpenNI REQUIRED)
```

When I use the line `add_subdirectory("foo")` in the first `CMakeLists.txt`, what actually happens? Does it search for a second `CMakeLists.txt` file in `foo`, and add the contents to the first? Will any variables defined the second file be available in the first? And specifically in this example, will the variable `${OpenNI_LIB}` be recognised in the first, given that it is defined in the second?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does it search for a second CMakeLists.txt file in foo

Yes, it does

> and add the contents to the first?

No it doesn't. It performs a number of configuring actions such as finding libraries etc and a generates separate Makefile and/or other build-time artifacts.

> And specifically in this example, will the variable ${OpenNI_LIB} be recognised in the first, given that it is defined in the second?

no, unless such a construction

```
find_library(OpenNI REQUIRED) # this sets variables for OpenNI
                              # in the context of foo/CMakeLists.txt
set(OpenNI_LIB ${OpenNI_LIB} PARENT_SCOPE) # this copies ${OpenNI_LIB}
                              # into the context of /CMakeLists.txt
```

is used in `foo/CMakeLists.txt`

By default variables defined in a subdirectory's CMakeLists.txt are also defined in the subdirectory's subdirectories, that is if `foo/` in turn contained `bar/` with its own `CMakeLists.txt`, then within `bar/`'s `CMakeLists.txt` ${OpenNI_LIB} would be set.

P.S. [message(STATUS "Some message with ${VAR}")](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/message.html) in doubtful places of `CMakeLists.txt` is your friend. Just look into cmake output.