# (soft question) Automated CMakeLists editing & updating

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32150576/multiple-cmakelists).

I am part of a team that uses CMake & Visual Studio 2017, and currently we have 3 levels of depth on the repository's CMakeLists:

1. solution-level CMakeList that defines which projects to include in the generated MSVS solution (there are over 40 projects in the repository and I only use 10 of them)
2. project-level CMakeList: basically sets a lot of variabes that hold directories, for use in the next CMakeList.
3. source-level CMakeList: include directories and framework-related macros

Now when I add some class to my source code, I need to update both the project-level and source-level CMakeLists, and if I create a new project, the solution-level CMakeList too.

This is far too manual, repetitive, and error prone (due to copying and pasting) for my taste and 
I was wondering if there's some tool that automates this process, as currently I have to manually change these files, which is an error-prone process (lots of copyng and pasting involved). I understand this is something that the IDE should take care of, however AFAIK Visual Studio doesn't provide this functionality, in fact adding a class through Visual Studio would be destroyed when re-generating the project (according to [this](https://cgold.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview/cmake-can-not.html#affecting-workflow)).

Basically: when I add a new source file, I want to have some kind of wizard that updates the CMake files according to a few inputs. Or, make Visual Studio properly work with CMake so I can use IDE features for all this.

Comment: `Or, make Visual Studio properly work with CMake` Are you only compiling for windows in visual c++? If so then why even use cmake, why not just use VS directly?

Comment: First because we are not compiling only for windows, we want to transition to Linux and then embedded. Secondly, if you arrive to a new project and they use CMake, you use CMake too and that's it.